# Javascript writing to window

Tags: javascript

How do you print onto seperate lines like in Java with println?

```
<script language = "javascript">

                    document.write("Your name is:" + fullName);

                    document.write("You were born in:" + birthYear);

                    document.write("You already had your birthday this year");

                    document.write("Your age is an <i>even</i> number.");


        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to print the data as html since that's the way a browser reads it. It's not like a console in Java. To make multiple lines you should use paragraph tags for each line or use a breake tag in the end.

```
document.write("<p>Your name is:" + fullName + "</p>");

document.write("Your name is:" + fullName + "<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
document.writeln("...");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_writeln.asp